# Binding events to an item inside a directive's content instead of the directive element itself

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a custom element directive:

```
<quest-card quest="quest"></quest-card>
```

The directive's template is:

```
<div class="col-md-6 card">
<h4>{{ quest.title }}</h4>

<p>{{ quest.description }}</p>
<hr/>
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="#">I did it</a>
```

What I want to do is bind a click function to the "a" element inside the card that calls a method in another controller, to do so I define the directive like this:

```
app.directive("questCard", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            quest: "="
        },
        templateUrl: "templates/quest-card.htm",
        require: "^questFeed",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, questFeedCtrl) {
            console.log(element.children().length);
        }
    }
});
```

In the link function element.children().length returns 0, I have also tried to select the a element using element.find("a") but that also returns 0. The html template shows that the anchor tag is inside of the div so my guess is that it should work.

This is one the first times I'm trying out a small project in angular so I could be doing something wrong.

Comment: take a look at `ng-click`. There are a significant number of event directives already built into angular

Comment: This code is not final yet. What I want to do later is execute a function in the questFeedCtrl (another controller) that is passed in in the link function. With an ng-click I don't think I can access that other controller.

Comment: sure you can. You have both scopes available in `link` already

Comment: I do have them in the link function, but how would I access the second controller from within an ng-click attribute?

Comment: `ng-click="doSomething()"`   ... define `doSomething()` in `link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to charlietfl:

In the template of the directive:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="#" ng-click="completeQuest()">I did it</a>
```

The directive:

```
app.directive("questCard", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            quest: "=",
            active: "="
        },
        templateUrl: "templates/quest-card.htm",
        require: "^questFeed",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, questFeedCtrl) {
            scope.completeQuest = function () {
                questFeedCtrl.completeQuest();
            }
        },
        controllerAs: "cardCtrl"
    }
});
```